# Rails Call A Method Lastly In Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller, action

I have something like that in my controller:

```
def index
  @votes = Vote.all
end

private

def search
  @votes = OtherVotes.all
end
```

I want to use search method in index action but I don't want to remove my @votes variable from index. If I use `before_action`, it calls method before the action so @votes doesn't change. Is it possible to call search method after my votes variable or ignore the variable without removing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally go with this method when I'm looking to build a simple search:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form

Create a method in your vote.rb file:

```
class Vote
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      self.where(:all, conditions: ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      self.where(:all)
    end
  end
end
```

This means when you do Vote.search('term'), you'll bring up any records with a similair name. Replace name for whatever term you're searching for (i.e. title or category).
If there is no search term entered this method simply returns every instance. This means you can leave your controller looking like this:

```
def index
  @votes = Vote.search(params[:search])
end
```

Finally the view for this would be something like:

```
<% form_tag votes_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

This will send a get request to the votes_path (the index action on your controller), with the search term parameter. If one is entered the search will return the relevant instances, and if not it will return all.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work at first. But then I wrote self.where instead of find and I made some little changes. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class TempController < ApplicationController
  after_action :search
  def index
   @votes = Vote.all
  end

  private

  def search
    @votes = OtherVotes.all
  end
end
```